# REST resources for a login/registration form

Tags: rest

I want to create REST login/registration URI in order to make a an existing user login or a new user to register. After a little search I found that most of such forms are designed using the following rules:

`GET /login` to get the login resource

`POST /login` to login and get back the user profile resource

`GET /register` to get the registration resource

`POST /register` to register and get back the new user profile resource

However, I think that this is not a 100% REST approach as one of the rules of REST is that resources should be nouns and not verbs (except from some special cases like a search api). What's the best solution for such a situation ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no one right answer to this, so I'll attempt to give some ideas on a common ways to solve this.

## Login

Login (aka Authentication) itself is typically handled in a non RESTful way, ourside, such as OAuth2. Should there really be a 'login' if HTTP is stateless? Every request should carry all the information to allow a server to authenticate the client. If you do want to really handle login as a RESTful endpoint, you could ask yourself: "What state am I changing? One way to answer this is that maybe you a *creating* a set of credentials". I'm assuming for now that you are looking for a best practice / common approach to this though, and not a very purist REST approach for this.

## Current user information

Getting the current user is often handled via an endpoint such as `/current-user` or `/whoami`. Doing a `GET` request on this could either yield information about the user, or it could immediately redirect to a canonical user endpoint such as `/users/1234`. Executing a `PUT` request could again either update the user, or return a redirect to the actual user endpoint.

## Registration

If you have a list of users on a resource like `/users`. It would kind of make sense to create a new user resource by doing a `POST` request on this collection.